# Update status of duplicate records in table except the record with min id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Employee
with fields **id ,name ,status**.Default value of status field is 0.
I want to do the following.If duplicates found on name in this table keep the status as 0 for the record with minimum id and  update the status to "5" for other duplicate records.
For eg:

```
   1    Ram     0
   2    Sham    0
   5    XYZ     0
   6    XYZ     0
   7    Sham    0
   8    SHam    0
   9    Yo YO   0
  10    Helo    0
  11    xyz     0
```

After running the query it should be:

```
   1    Ram     0
   2    Sham    0
   5    XYZ     0
   6    XYZ     5
   7    Sham    5
   8    Sham    5
   9    Yo YO   0
  10    Helo    0
  11    xyz     5
```

Could anyone suggest.Thanks...

Comment: When asking these sorts of questions, please consider providing a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Employee` t1
JOIN (
    SELECT min(id) mid, name, count(*) cnt FROM `Employee` 
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING cnt > 1
) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.id != t2.mid
SET t1.status = 5
```

This must be faster than using subquery.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4759/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
update Employee
set [status]=5
where id not in (select min(id) from Employee
                    group by name)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50da6/1)**